# Ctrl P isn't working when connecting my armature to my mesh!

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

Everyone keeps saying <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> in all of the tutorials and all of the helps forums but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> just isn't working for me. If anyone can link to an online file that I can see or anyone have any suggestions why it isn't working. I mean, I just downloaded 2.79 today and I've been working with Blender for years, so why is this not working for me?[image]

Comment: Ctrl+P does not rig a mesh to an armature, it makes a a mesh stick to the armature position as a whole. Rigging allows to deform the mesh with bones. You need an armature modifier on the mesh. The next step would be to replace the automatic (envelope) rigging by your own.

Comment: @Dimali that's not correct in the case of armatures.You are right, Ctrl+P usually is just simple parenting from one object to another, but when you parent something to an armature, you get a little menu with options such as "Armature Deform with automatic weigths" which is what OP is looking for.

Comment: @Lynn you mean Blender 2.79 not 2.9, right? Could you please provide a link to the tutorial you are using?

Answer (score 2):

Based on your question it might be very simple:
If you really tried connecting an armature to a mesh, then it can't work, because it has to be the other way around.

First select the Mesh, then hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> while selecting the Armature, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and you should get this menu:
[image]